# Can't get an output(AngularJS) from server reponse(WebAPI)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I really get stuck. Can't understand, why I can't output the server response.

[Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlzYx.gif)

[Server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWtdY.gif)

Part of index.html code

```html
<table class="table" ng-controller="FileListCtrl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Less 10Mb</td>
      <td>10Mb - 50Mb</td>
      <td>More 100Mb</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{smallFiles}}</td>
      <td>{{averageFiles}}</td>
      <td>{{bigFiles}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

fileListCtrl.js

```js
(function()
{
  "use strict";
  angular
         .module("fileManagement")
         .controller("FileListCtrl",
                      ["fileResource",
                      FileListCtrl]);

  function FileListCtrl(fileResource){
     fileResource.get();
  }
}
());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign the data, which is coming back to a variables, when your promise is resolved.

for example:

```
function FileListCtrl(fileResource, $scope){
 fileResource.get().then(function(responseData) {
     $scope.smallFiles = responseData.smallFiles;
     $scope.averageFiles = responseData.averageFiles;
     $scope.bigFiles = responseData.bigFiles;
 });
}
```

Comment: Does fileResource.get returns a promise ? If yes, then try. ->

function FileListCtrl(fileResource, $scope){
 fileResource.get().then(function (responseData) {
    $scope.smallFiles = responseData.smallFiles;

})
}